# Restrict the predefined CloudWatch metric namespace access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-billing

There are a no. of predefined metric namespace present in CloudWatch console.
There is 1 such '**AWS/Billing**' metric namespace are visible which is not required.

Can someone suggest a solution to either one points below :-

1. block this 'billing' metrics so no one able to view this metrics.
2. The metrics is visible but no-one is able to view the data in it.

Any of the above points solution is helpful.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you could use [cloudwatch:namespace](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/iam-cw-condition-keys-namespace.html) IAM condition key to limit access to these metrics. The docs I linked provide some examples, so you would have to try and see.

The alternative is not to give users access to `us-east-1`. These billing metrics are only visible in this region, so just do not allow your users to access the region if possible.

Comment: hi sorry for late reply. thank you for your help.